# Repeated measures regression using GLMM if there are varying numbers of measurements per subject

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, glmm

*Aim*: To develop a predictive model for an infection, judged condition negative/positive by an assumed gold-standard.

*Data*: Longitudinal data for a number of subjects, at each time point comprising a binary response variable (infection negative/positive), as well as a number of explanatory variables, some continuous (eg. white cell count) and others binary (eg. gender). There are a variable number of time points per subject, and some have only one.

*Question*: Is GLMM a suitable method for analysis and if so is any pre-processing required to account for the varying numbers of measurements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use mixed effects logistic regression to produce a predictive model for your binary response variable. For example, have a look at the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package, and examples [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods_MixMod.html#predictions) and [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Dynamic_Predictions.html).

Comment: Thanks. So it is ok that some subjects have only one time point?

Comment: Yes, it will work also with these subjects.